# How do I upgrade my Ubuntu Touch Preview to Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I use Galaxy Nexus with ubuntu touch preview (the absolute first version) installed.
I use Saucy Salamander as desktop.

Hos do I install the newer Ubuntu Touch on it?
(I've got no backup). Do I need to reinstall Android?

I want easy copy/paste terminal commands that I can follow.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way: Reinstall android and follow ubuntu on phones guide:
[Ubuntu phone](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install)

It shouldnt take too long to install it.